# Duktape get array value

Tags: arrays, duktape

I can paste array with values by key in global like this:

```cpp
duk_push_global_object(ctx);
duk_idx_t arr_idx = duk_push_array(ctx);
duk_push_string(ctx, "string by key");
duk_put_prop_string(ctx, arr_idx, "key");
duk_put_prop_string(ctx, -2, "global_array");
duk_pop(ctx);
```

but how I can get value by key from global later?

P.S.: Sorry for my English.

Comment: https://wiki.duktape.org/howtoiteratearray https://wiki.duktape.org/howtonativepersistentreferences

Comment: Mind you, this is an array, but it's being used more like an object.

Answer (score 2):

The C code you posted is equivalent to the following Javascript (is this correct?):

```js
var t = [];  // not actually registered into global object
t.key = 'string by key';
global_array = t;
```

To read back **global_array.key**:

```cpp
duk_get_global_string(ctx, "global_array");
duk_get_prop_string(ctx, -1, "key");
/* ... use the value, then pop it */
duk_pop(ctx);  /* pop global_array */
```

By the way, you could simplify the code in your question as follows:

```cpp
duk_idx_t arr_idx = duk_push_array(ctx);
duk_push_string(ctx, "string by key");
duk_put_prop_string(ctx, arr_idx, "key");
duk_put_global_string(ctx, -2, "global_array");
```

Answer (score -1):

It took me a really long time to figure out how this works exactly. The docs and examples can be rather confusing when it comes to the Duktape stack indices and pushing and popping things. Let me try to present it all in an organized fashion, piece by piece, with extra spacing to help make it clearer. (This also helps me to solidify my own understanding.)

*Note that in the case of the OP's question, you would use `duk_get_prop_string()` instead of `duk_get_prop_index()`, since he's really using it more like an object via. key->value access than an array using indices.*

---

Let's say you have JS arrays nested in an array like this that you want to access using an arbitrary c++ `accessArray()` function:

```js
//Javascript, calling a c++ function, passing nested arrays.
accessArray([
  [ "str1", "str2" ],
  //Varying the number of elements.
  [ "str3", "str4", "str5" ]
]);
```

Then you register the `accessArray()` function in c++ like this:

```cpp
//First, push the c++ function onto the Duktape stack.
//Make sure to put the # of arguments accessArray expects; in this case, it's 1.
duk_push_c_function(duktapeContext, accessArray, 1);
//Then, register that c++ function as a global JS ("string") variable,
//to access it like in the above JS.
duk_put_global_string(duktapeContext, "accessArray");
```

With that context, you would create the c++ function like this:

```cpp
#include <string>

//The format of a duk_c_function.
duk_ret_t accessArray(duk_context* dc)
{
  //Note: You could also first check if the parameter is an array using duk_is_array().
  
  //Determine the number of arguments in the array parameter. In this case, the array is
  //the first parameter, so it will be at the bottom of the function call stack,
  //at index 0.
  duk_size_t outerArraySize = duk_get_length(dc, 0);
  
  //Loop through the outer array.
  for (duk_size_t outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < outerArraySize; ++outerIndex)
  {
    //Get the property at [outerIndex] of the outer array (still) at
    //stack index 0.
    //This function puts the property at the top of the stack, at index -1.
    //We'll pop it later when finished.
    duk_get_prop_index(dc, 0, outerIndex);
    
      //Now it gets a little more complicated. This time, we use the property at the top
      //of the stack, at index -1, which is the inner array.
      //First, we have to get its size.
      //Note that this function merely returns a value; it does not change the stack.
      duk_size_t innerArraySize = duk_get_length(dc, -1);
      
      //Loop through the inner array.
      for (duk_size_t innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < innerArraySize; ++innerIndex)
      {
```

```cpp
        //Just like before, we get the property at [innerIndex] of the inner array
        //at index -1.
        //This puts the property at the top of the stack, so we'll need to pop it
        //when finished.
        duk_get_prop_index(dc, -1, innerIndex);
          
          //We know/expect it as a string.
          std::string myString = duk_to_string(dc, -1);
          
        //Pop the inner array's property off the stack; now, the inner array will be
        //back at the top of the stack, at index -1.
        duk_pop(dc);
      }
    
    //Pop the property that we got earlier using duk_get_prop_index(); now, the
    //outer array will be back at the top of the stack, at index -1.
    duk_pop(dc);
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

---

So, to bring things full circle: When this `accessArray()` function gets called, the Duktape stack looks like this:

```
(bottom of stack) [ outer array ] (top of stack)
```

Whether you access the outer array using index `0`, the stack's bottom index, or `-1`, the stack's top index, there is no difference currently.

When you call `duk_get_prop_index(dc, 0, outerIndex)`, it pushes an element of the outer array onto the top of the stack:

```
(bottom of stack) [ outer array, inner array ] (top of stack)
```

Now, index `0` refers to the outer array, and index `-1` has changed to access the inner array. You can then access elements of the inner array via. e.g. `duk_get_prop_index(dc, -1, innerIndex)`, pushing yet another element onto the top of the stack:

```
(bottom of stack) [ outer array, inner array, inner array element ] (top of stack)
```

and then convert that inner array element to a string using `duk_to_string(dc, -1)`. Then, you can pop the inner array element using `duk_pop(dc)`:

```
(bottom of stack) [ outer array, inner array ] (top of stack)
```

and again pop the inner array itself using `duk_pop(dc)`:

```
(bottom of stack) [ outer array ] (top of stack)
```

---

See also:

- https://wiki.duktape.org/howtoiteratearray
- https://duktape.org/api.html